# Is it possible to send a Office communicator message from web page?

Tags: ms-office, office-communicator

Is it possible to send a Office communicator message from web page? Currently my webpage can actually send a message now but after deploying it to our web server it gives the following error below.

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {8885370D-B33E-44B7-875D-28E403CF9270} failed due to the following error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).

Answer (score 0):

how are you calling the Lync API?
It sounds like a COM automation failure.
Try logging into the server and running the webpage locally. 
Do you still get the problem?

Some basic points:

1. Make sure you are using Microsoft Lync 2010 Client API
2. Make sure the browser you are using for testing supports ActiveX controls (e.g. Internet Explorer)
3. If you are not using Internet Explorer for testing, try this browser.